# modifying a function for better sub setting in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)

ticker<-c("BABA")

# download option chain from yahoo finance, for ticker "BABA" & exp= "2023-06-23"
options<-getOptionChain(ticker,Exp="2023-06-23")
# seperate call/put options and display only Strike, Last Price, Volume
call_option<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]
put_option<-options$puts[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

#getting the updated stock price
price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
price<-price$close

#subsetting the data & merge into 1 data frame
floor<-round(price-5,-1)
ceiling<-round(price+5,-1)

c<-subset(call_option,call_option[,c("Strike")]>=floor & call_option[,c("Strike")]<=ceiling)
p<-subset(put_option,put_option[,c("Strike")]>=floor & put_option[,c("Strike")]<=ceiling)

output<-data.frame(c,p)

output

 Strike Last   Vol Strike.1 Last.1 Vol.1
22     80 7.00    12       80   0.02  5481
23     81 6.25    10       81   0.04    73
24     82 6.40     1       82   0.05   704
25     83 4.30    37       83   0.09   328
26     84 3.15     9       84   0.16  1053
27     85 2.52  1752       85   0.32  3582
28     86 1.87   456       86   0.61  1576
29     87 1.34  3203       87   1.01  2458
30     88 0.85  4938       88   1.65   972
31     89 0.55  3894       89   2.30   835
32     90 0.36 13742       90   3.09   376
```

I then try to turn above lines into one function:

```
test_function<-function(ticker,exp){
  options<-getOptionChain(ticker,Exp=exp)
  price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
  price<-price$close
  floor<-round(price-5,-1)
  ceiling<-round(price+5,-1)
  c<-subset(call_option,call_option[,c("Strike")]>=floor & call_option[,c("Strike")]<=ceiling)
  p<-subset(put_option,put_option[,c("Strike")]>=floor & put_option[,c("Strike")]<=ceiling)
  result<-data.frame(c,p)
  print(result)
}

Strike Last   Vol Strike.1 Last.1 Vol.1
22     80 7.00    12       80   0.02  5481
23     81 6.25    10       81   0.04    73
24     82 6.40     1       82   0.05   704
25     83 4.30    37       83   0.09   328
26     84 3.15     9       84   0.16  1053
27     85 2.52  1752       85   0.32  3582
28     86 1.87   456       86   0.61  1576
29     87 1.34  3203       87   1.01  2458
30     88 0.85  4938       88   1.65   972
31     89 0.55  3894       89   2.30   835
32     90 0.36 13742       90   3.09   376
```

What I would like to ask here is that, as you can see, I am sub setting the data in a manual and stupid way like below:

```
floor<-round(price-5,-1)
ceiling<-round(price+5,-1)
```

I believe the price of BABA was 87 something when I downloaded the price data; ultimately I would like to round the last traded price to at-the-money level, and display only 10 strike prices up and 10 strikes price down in the data frame. In this example, it just so happens that the strike interval of BABA is 1. This figure can be something else depending on tickers, for example, TSLA, its strike interval is 2.5, and so my lines would not work well in this case. Is there a better way to round the market price based on strike interval and display +/-10 strike prices based on the rounded price? Thank you so much for your time and help.